What is the purpose of RegisteredStyle<T> in react native?
I was working on a utility function that would extract the color value from a given arg of type StyleProp<TextStyle>. I noticed that StyleProp<TextStyle> evaluates to
type StyleProp<T> =
  | T
  | RegisteredStyle<T>
  | RecursiveArray<T | RegisteredStyle<T> | Falsy>
  | Falsy;
type Falsy = undefined | null | false;
interface RecursiveArray<T>
  extends Array<T | ReadonlyArray<T> | RecursiveArray<T>> {}

/** Keep a brand of 'T' so that calls to `StyleSheet.flatten` can take `RegisteredStyle<T>` and return `T`. */

type RegisteredStyle<T> = number & {__registeredStyleBrand: T};


I understand Falsy and RecursiveArray<T>. What is the point of RegisteredStyle<T>?
The comment above the declaration doesn't help either. What was the idea and what is its use case? How do I ignore or handle that case in my utility function to extract the color value from a StyleProp<TextStyle>.
